# ssocr @my_libs@: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ocr

I recently downloaded [ssocr](http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~auerswal/ssocr/), and also install all dependencies. But when I want to run make I get the following error:

> cc: error: @my_libs@: No such file or directory
>   make: *** [ssocr] Error 1

I have no idea what is the problem and also can't find any solution for it. 
The os i have tryed to intall the ssocr is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr)

UPDATE (whole output)

> cc   ssocr.o imgproc.o help.o  -L/usr/local/lib -lImlib2 @my_libs@ -o ssoc
>
> cc: error: @my_libs@: No such file or directory
>
> make: *** [ssocr] Error 1

Comment: can you provide whole output of make command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the link-command comes from

imlib2-config --libs

Try to repair the imlib2-config output. Second, I had also to add -lm. The commandline looks for me like

cc   ssocr.o imgproc.o help.o  -L/usr/lib64 -lImlib2 -L/lib64 -lX11 -lm -o ssocr